# action wp_set_comment_status never gets fired when i change the comment status

Tags: actions, comments

I want to run some code on comment status change so using the action `wp_set_comment_status` but it seem to never fired when comment status gets changed. I am using wordpress 3.3.1.

**Here is a simple code which doesn't work for me:**

```
add_action('wp_set_comment_status ', 'update_business_rating_avg');

function update_business_rating_avg($comment_ID, $status){
    update_option( 'business', 'checked' );
}
```

There was a same bug on the wp version `2.8.2` and it was fixed later on. Not sure if i am doing something wrong or not.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8863

The [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) says about the action:

**wp_set_comment_status:** Runs when the status of a comment changes. Action function arguments: comment ID, status string indicating the new status ("delete", "approve", "spam", "hold").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is showing an empty space in the hook name

```
add_action('wp_set_comment_status ', 'update_business_rating_avg');
                                 ^
```

try removing it

```
add_action('wp_set_comment_status', 'update_business_rating_avg');
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks! Never imagine that might be a problem :S